# Page structure breaks when zooming out

Tags: html, css

Im wondering if anyone else has come across this problem when designing websites. Basically every time I zoom far out from my webpage the structure breaks and images and containers jump in to other parts of the page.

I have tried my very best to avoid this by measuring every div to the last pixel but this issue occurs, is there any tips for sorting this problem out.

Sorry that I cannot show an example, everything is on my localhost.

Comment: Do not specify height/width in pixels. Specify them in `%`.

Comment: Try to grab the relevant code from your localhost and post it in your question or on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Without any code it's impossible to know what your problem is.

Comment: @Vikas it's not always possible to use %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better website which doesnot breaks on zooming , please go through the following links.

1. [Choosing the Dimensions for Your Web Page
   Layout](http://www.elated.com/articles/choosing-dimensions-for-your-web-page-layout/)
2. [How to create flexible sites quickly using standards like CSS and
   XHTML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-rapid/)
3. [In Search of the Holy
   Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/)

Also here is the [Blueprint Tests: grid.css](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html). Check that link by zooming!!!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

use html table tag right after your body tag when you put your body content in a table the content take automatically the width and height of their cells so when zooming it should not be a problem